# Split HTML into separate files based on a string

Tags: html, joomla, split, notepad

I have a Joomla article which is long, but I need to separate it into individual articles. First stage would be to separate the HTML code into separate files.

Any way to do this, based on a string (for example: Date in the HTML code)?

Comment: You could do this with PHP. The approach would be somehting like this: Create a loop with a regular expression that finds the needle in the haystack and puts everything until the needle in a variable. Remove everything until that needle from the haystack and write the variable to a file. Name the file 'untill_needle_[iteration_number].html'. When your loop is finished, you will have many files.

Answer (score 1):

To separate into individual small articles you can use `PageBreak`. You can read this article
Splitting a long Article into multiple linked pages
https://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_a_long_Article_into_multiple_linked_pages

You can also read a nice article on customising the pagebreak plugin, so you can create your own style:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/page-break-viral/

If thats not enough than there is a free plugin which can customise the Pagebreak the way you want
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/pagebreakmyjspace